# How to change selected row background of listview in winfoms

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to change background of selected row if number in row is 0. I have try following but not worked for me.

```
list.SelectedItems[0].BackColor = Color.Red;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are showing this list of data in data-grid or grid-view.If its true you can follow the bellow way.which is applicable for VB.kindly check the C# syntax but the approach is same.

```
dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect

dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.White
dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = Color.Black
```

If you used Listview you can check bellow code .

```
private void txtList_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
  {
        item.BackColor = Color.LightSteelBlue;
        return;
  }
}
```

Comment: The question is about a ListView not DataGridView

Comment: Thanks Anil but Questioner didn't mentioned listview or anything else although his code belongs to list view for what i added the scenario for list view as well.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, ListView uses the default design colors of windows for the selection color, so if you want to change it, you will have to draw the item yourself.

You can do this by setting the "OwnerDraw" property of the ListView to true and writing your own logic for the ListView's "DrawItem" event.

So something like this:

```
private void listView1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.Selected)
    {
        if (e.Item.Index == 0)
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, e.Bounds);
        }
        else
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Highlight, e.Bounds);
        }                       
    }
    else
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, e.Bounds);
    }

    e.DrawText(TextFormatFlags.TextBoxControl);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ObjectListView instead:

```
ObjListView.UseCustomSelectionColors = true;
ObjListView.HighlightBackgroundColor = Color.Green; 
ObjListView.UnfocusedHighlightBackgroundColor = Color.Green;
```

[ObjectListView](https://sourceforge.net/projects/objectlistview/)